# How to install libmysql under Cygwin?

Tags: node.js, cygwin, libmysql

I am trying to build db-mysql extension for NodeJS under Cygwin. The problem is, that it requires libmysql development libraries and include files. I have no idea how to install (and where to get) this stuff to work with Cygwin. Under Ubuntu i would write something like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

But this is not possible under Cygwin. Also there is no available libmysql package when I run Cygwin's setup.exe. Does anybody know how to solve this isue?

I have installed wamp under Windows which includes MySQL database. I would like to use databases from that installation under Cygwin, is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's available from [Cygwin Ports](http://sourceware.org/cygwinports), a large repository of additional Cygwin packages that can be installed through Cygwin's setup.exe.